# Adjusting the page-layout in lightning experience

Tags: lightning-experience, lightning, app-builder

How to remove the add components section in the (as shown in the below image) page layout and extend the related list added to full extent in lightning experience.[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you go to lightning app builder click the new button, select new record page, then select the header and one column template. (Spring 16)